# The right way to call a service function on sails.js as soon as I start sails.js

Tags: php, service, sails.js, dnode

I want that my sails.js application communicates with a php client.
I've create a new [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) server service in sails.js for that.
This service can start the dnode server.
Currently I start the server with a controller by a request, but the server should always listen for clients.
What is the right way to start the server as soon as I start sails.js, but only if the rest was fully charged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with dnoe but I think you want to use the [bootstrap](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/config.bootstrap) function inside of the config folder. it gets executed right before the server lifts with your models and services ready to use.

Comment: Thank you, that I had overlooked.